# HTTP endpoints deprecated in SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I hear HTTP endpoints are being deprecated in SQL Server. What takes its place in future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deprecated in favor of [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx). So basically you would write and host WCF services in .NET which will directly talk to the SQL database and then consume those services from client applications.

Comment: Absolutely. `basicHttpBinding` is standard interoperable SOAP binding.

Comment: So.. what is the difference between basicHttpBinding (declared as a endpoint binding) and HTTP Endpoint ?